# How to generate random numbers from fixed set

Tags: matlab, random

I've got fixed numbers: -3, -1,  1,  3. How do I randomly generate a matrix like the following?

```
 1  -1  -3  -1

 3  -3  -3   3   

 3   3   1  -1  

 3  -3   3  -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `randi` to create random index values into your vector of possible values:

```
x = [-3 -1 1 3]
y = randi(length(x),[5 5]);
y = x(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although [@nkjt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607871/2586922) is probably the way to go, if you have the Statistics Toolbox you can simplify a little using [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html) (with replacement):

```
result = NaN(3,6); %// define required size
result(:) = randsample([-3 -1 1 3], numel(result), true);
```

Or, if the original numbers are equally spaced as in your example, you can solve it in one line:

```
result = 2*randi(4,[3 6])-5; %// "2" and "5" as per your original values
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

- `randperm` Random permutation

Comment: That will give only one row, and without repeated elements. In the OP example there are rows with repeated elements